# Close pause menù and come back in game screen - java game with LIBGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I need your help for a simple problem.

I implemented my Java game using LibGDX library.
My Game has following structure:
- main menù with some buttons;
- game screen;
- pause menù opened when user press P keyword.

The probles is the this. When I press P, pause menù opens. If I click on MainMenù button in pause menù , the screen go on main menù. After that, If I press on game button , it appears pause menù screen and not game screen.

How can I solve this?

---

```
public class MenuPause implements Screen {
private Skin skin;
private Stage stage;
private MyGdxGame game;
private Level level=new Level(true);    
private World world;
private GameScreen8Bit GS;
private int era;

/*****Button *******/
private Button saveGame;
private Button loadGame;
private Button continueGame;
private Button exitGame;
private Button mainMenu;
/******************/


private SpriteBatch batch;
private TextureAtlas atlas;
private TextureRegion imagetexture;


public MenuPause(MyGdxGame game, int era){
    this.game=game;

}
private void createBasicSkin(){
      //Create a font

    atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("images/textures/game.atlas"));
      BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont();
      skin = new Skin();
      skin.add("default", font);

      //Create a texture
      Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap((int)Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/4,(int)Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/10, Pixmap.Format.RGB888);
      pixmap.setColor(Color.WHITE);
      pixmap.fill();
      skin.add("background",new Texture(pixmap));

      //Create a button style
      TextButton.TextButtonStyle textButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
      textButtonStyle.up = skin.newDrawable("background", Color.GRAY);
      textButtonStyle.down = skin.newDrawable("background", Color.DARK_GRAY);
      textButtonStyle.checked = skin.newDrawable("background", Color.DARK_GRAY);
      textButtonStyle.over = skin.newDrawable("background", Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
      textButtonStyle.font = skin.getFont("default");
      skin.add("default", textButtonStyle);

    }


@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3();

    touchPos.set((Gdx.input.getX()), (Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-Gdx.input.getY()), 0);

    if(exitGame.mousePassage(touchPos))
    {
        exitGame=new Button(atlas.findRegion("exitNoPressed"));
        exitGame.setPos(0, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        exitGame=new Button(atlas.findRegion("exit"));
        exitGame.setPos(0, 0);
    }
    if(loadGame.mousePassage(touchPos))
    {
        loadGame=new Button(atlas.findRegion("loadNoPressed"));
        loadGame.setPos(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2-atlas.findRegion("loadNoPressed").getRegionWidth()/2, (Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2));

    }
    else
    {
        loadGame=new Button(atlas.findRegion("load"));
        loadGame.setPos(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2-atlas.findRegion("load").getRegionWidth()/2, (Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2));
    }
    if(saveGame.mousePassage(touchPos))
    {
        saveGame=new Button(atlas.findRegion("saveNoPressed"));
         saveGame.setPos(0 , Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/3);
    }
    else
    {
        saveGame=new Button(atlas.findRegion("save"));
         saveGame.setPos(0 , Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/3);
    }
    if(continueGame.mousePassage(touchPos))
    {
        continueGame=new Button(atlas.findRegion("continueNoPressed"));
        continueGame.setPos((Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - atlas.findRegion("continueNoPressed").getRegionWidth()) , 0);

    }
    else
    {
        continueGame=new Button(atlas.findRegion("continue"));
        continueGame.setPos((Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - atlas.findRegion("continue").getRegionWidth()) , 0);

    }
    if(mainMenu.mousePassage(touchPos))
    {
        mainMenu=new Button(atlas.findRegion("mainNoPressed"));
        mainMenu.setPos(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2-atlas.findRegion("mainNoPressed").getRegionWidth()/2 , 0);

    }
    else
    {
        mainMenu=new Button(atlas.findRegion("main"));
        mainMenu.setPos((Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2-atlas.findRegion("main").getRegionWidth()/2) , 0);

    }


     if(Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Input.Buttons.LEFT)){



         if(exitGame.isPressed(touchPos)){
            int n= JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Sei sicuro di volere uscire dal gioco?", "EXIT", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            if(n==0)
            {
                System.exit(0); 
            }
        }

        if(loadGame.isPressed(touchPos)){
            new LoadGame(level,false);
        }


        if(saveGame.isPressed(touchPos)){
            SavePanel savePanel = new SavePanel( level, game,false);
            savePanel.save();
        }
        if(mainMenu.isPressed(touchPos)){
            dispose();
            this.dispose();
            game.setScreen(new MainMenu(game,0));

        }
        if(continueGame.isPressed(touchPos)){
            //game.setScreen(new MainMenu(game));//mainMenu non funziona...eccezione
            //game.setScreen(new GameScreen8Bit(game,level));
        }
    }


   batch.begin();
    batch.draw(imagetexture,0 , 0);
    saveGame.draw(batch);
    loadGame.draw(batch);
    continueGame.draw(batch);
    exitGame.draw(batch);
    mainMenu.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
}

@Override
public void show() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    createBasicSkin();
    saveGame= new Button(atlas.findRegion("save"));
    saveGame.setPos(0 , Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/3);
    loadGame=new Button(atlas.findRegion("load"));
    loadGame.setPos(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2-atlas.findRegion("load").getRegionWidth()/2, (Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2));

    continueGame=new Button(atlas.findRegion("continue"));
    continueGame.setPos((Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - atlas.findRegion("continue").getRegionWidth()) , 0);

    exitGame=new Button(atlas.findRegion("exit"));
    exitGame.setPos(0, 0);

    mainMenu=new Button(atlas.findRegion("main"));
    mainMenu.setPos(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2-atlas.findRegion("load").getRegionWidth()/2, 0);

    Texture immagine=new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/ghiacciairid.png"));


    if(era==1)
    {
        immagine=new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/8bitrid.png"));
    }
    else if(era==2)
    {
        immagine=new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/16bitrid.png"));
    }
    else if(era==3)
    {
        immagine=new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/3d.png"));
    }
    imagetexture =new TextureRegion(immagine,640,480);
    imagetexture.setRegionHeight(480);
    imagetexture.setRegionWidth(640);
}
@Override
public void hide() {
    dispose();
}

@Override
public void pause() {
}

@Override
public void resume() {
}

@Override
public void dispose() {

 }
}
```

Comment: ok @donfuxx can you help me with my problem? :(

Comment: You are doing to many things inside the render method! Be aware that this method gets called about 60 times per second.

Comment: @donfuxx ok I will fix the code later. My concern now is to solve the problem,please.

Comment: It is not only about code cosmetics. Creating a bunch of buttons etc. each frame actually is the problem

Comment: @donfuxx ok can you help me to fix it? What is the way to solve my cosmetics problems?

Comment: Well, it is not a cosmetic problem ;-) The problem is to repeat things every frame that you only need to do once. You should move the creation of the Buttons etc. out of render method.

Comment: Ok thanks...can i move that in the show metod?or in which metod?

Comment: Yes, as a start move all those creations of buttons out of render() and into show().
Each frame you also draw all of your menues. You need to do a complete redesign of the logic.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a year old, but I am answering anyway.

Don't create menu items every frame in render. Create once.

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen{

private State state;  //this keeps track of where 


public static enum State{
    RUNNING, PAUSE, SAVEGAME
}


public MenuPause(MyGdxGame game, int era){
    this.game=game;
    state = State.RUNNING

}

@Override
public void show() {
    //do the loading and creating here
}


@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    switch(state){
        case RUNNING:   running();
                        break;

        case PAUSE:     pause();
                        break;

        case SAVEGAME:  savegame();
                        break;

        default:        break;
    }

}


private void running(){

}

private void pause(){

}

private void savegame(){

}
```

}